# Solution to Seiberg-Witten monopole equation

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-equations

To understand some physics problem, I want to know if there is (**non-$L^2$** or $L^2$) solution to the Seiberg-Witten equation on $\mathbb{R}^4$
\begin{equation}
    {D}_A \psi = 0\\
    F_A^+ = i\zeta\omega + \sigma(\psi)
\end{equation}
where $\zeta$ is a real number, and $\omega$ is the standard symplectic form on $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I know that when $\zeta = 0$, a square-integrable solution would imply $\psi = 0$ everywhere, because by Weitzenbock formula
\begin{equation}
    D_A^*{D_A}\psi = \nabla _A^*{\nabla _A}\psi  + \frac{s}{4}\psi  + \frac{1}{2}F_A^ + \psi 
\end{equation}
and then using the S-W equation itself, one gets
\begin{equation}
    \int {{{\left| {{\nabla _A}\psi } \right|}^2} + \frac{1}{4}{{\left| \psi  \right|}^4} + \left( {i\zeta\omega  \cdot \psi ,\psi } \right)}  =  - \frac{1}{4}\int {s{{\left| \psi  \right|}^2}} 
\end{equation}
which forces $\psi = 0$ when $s = \zeta = 0$

> But I wonder what happens if $\zeta \ne 0$?
>
> Is there known solution (non-$L^2$ is also good) to the equation? Any
>   reference would be great.

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The noncompactness is bound to create trouble. For what to expect  in the case of a compact symplectic manifold  check  page 272-275 of  [these notes](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/swnotes.pdf)  Kronheimer and Mrowka have investigated the noncompact  case  in a [beautiful paper going back to the mid 90s.](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~kronheim/monocont.pdf)    Their main result seems to say that the answer to your question is positive. $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$

**Comment 1.**  If we think  $\bR^4=\bC^2$, then we have

$$\Psi=\alpha+\beta,\;\;\alpha\in \Omega^0(\bC^2),\;\; \beta\in \Omega^{0,2}(\bC^2). $$

Closing our eyes and pretending  that $\bR^4$  is compact    we deduce  from the  SW equations $\newcommand{\bpar}{\bar{\partial}}$

$$ F_A^{0,2}=0,\;\;\bpar_A \alpha=0=\bpar_A^*\beta, $$

$$\alpha\beta=0, $$

$$ F_A\wedge \omega= \sqrt{-1}(|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2-\zeta) dV. $$

One of $\alpha$ or $\beta$ is identically zero.  If $F_A\wedge \omega \to 0$ at $\infty$ then   either $|\alpha|^2\to \zeta$ or $|\beta|^2\to-\zeta$ at $\infty$ vilating the $L^2$-assumption on $\Psi$.   As in the paper  of Kronheimer and Mrowka, you need to impose a different condition at $\infty$ to get nontrivial solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (But the way, your link to notes contains some invalid character after ".pdf"). It is intriguing to see "contact structure" appearing in the title, since my question also has a K-contact structure origin, but in different setting: near some points on a 5d K-contact $M$, certain physics equations reduce to SW equation on $\mathbb{R}^4$ plus an equation along the fifth direction.

Comment: I fixed the broken link. The paper  of Kronheimer Mrowka refers to $4$-manifolds bounding   contact $3$-manifolds.  As a curiosity,  about 15 years ago I looked at SW equations on K-contact 3-manifolds and reduce them to vortices on the base.

Comment: I guess what we've been mentioning are along the same line (and do you mean your paper <Three-dimensional Seiberg-Witten theory
>?). In physics, your situation should correspond to Higgs branch localization (see arXiv:1312.6078), where "BPS equation" reduces to vortex eq. in neighborhoods of closed Reeb orbits ($\sim S^1\times \mathbb{R}^2$), and the "partition function" receives contributions from these vortices. I focus on 5d, so my situation is: 5d K-contact $M$ and SW equation.

Comment: I meant my papers on SW theory on Seifert manifolds. As for $\mathbb{R}^4$  its noncompactness  worries me  and  that is why  I am reluctant to make  definite statements.  A good guide on dealing with noncompactness could be  Jaffe & Taubes' book on vortices and monopoles. Its precise title escapes me at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps you mean <Vortices and Monopoles: Structure of Static Gauge Theories>. Well, for kink, vortex, monopole and their physics applications, non-compactness doesn't seem like much a problem (solutions on $\mathbb{R}^{1, 2, 3}$ are standard and taught in our QFT class). So I'm not sure what they could tell me about how to deal with spinorial SW-eq. on $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: So far, apart from Kronheimer and Mrowka's paper, I came across basically 2 types of discussions (in the case of $\zeta = 0$) on SW-eq. on $\mathbb{R}^4$: (1) There is no non-zero $L^2$ solution; (2) There are singular solutions that blow up near origin, and one needs to go to (-+++) signature to have these solutions.

Comment: I meant the book Jaffe, Taubes: Vortices and Monopoles, Birkauser 1980.  I don't have enough room so I will   add a comment to my answer.

Comment: I'm confused by your new comments: shouldn't we have something like $F^{0,2} = \alpha \bar \beta$ and $\bar \partial \alpha + \bar \partial^* \beta = 0$? And actually non-$L^2$ solutions are also welcome, for my situation.

Comment: In my notes on SW you can see an explanation  why $\alpha\bar{\beta}=0$. This was observed  and proved by Witten in his first paper (for mathematicians) on monopoles. http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411102